# Debian 9.3 does not support encryption in losetup

Tags: linux, encryption, debian-stretch

I am struggling to mount an encrypted file left over form a previous installation of Debian 7. The version of `losetup` installed by Debian 9 does not have the -e (nor the --encryption) option. Can you advise? How do I mount an encrypted loop filesystem from a file.

Comment: Directly from Debian 9 `man` page of `losetup`: "Cryptoloop  is  no  longer  supported  in  favor of dm-crypt.  For more details see cryptsetup(8)."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, the question has been answered here (as well as by Marek Rost):

[How to mount an old encrypted disk on Ubuntu](https://superuser.com/questions/563081/how-to-mount-an-old-encrypted-disk-on-ubuntu)

Just to add an easy search target:

If you get:

`losetup -e
losetup: invalid option -- 'e'`

ANSWER:

Instead of:

`losetup -e twofish /dev/loop1 $file`

do:

`losetup /dev/loop1 $file
cryptsetup open /dev/loop1 encryptedfile --type plain -c twofish`

and mount /dev/mapper/encryptedfile

Works on Debian 9.3.

Comment: The losetup man page should really mention that it's a "plain mode" dm-crypt / cryptsetup, I don't see it mentioned in cryptsetup's man page either. +1